# Create a connection string / connect to a database in asp.net?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, web-config

I am trying to publish a website to make it go live and need to connect to a database. Currently I am using:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="UniversityContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=RoomAudit;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\RoomAuditSystem.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
</connectionStrings>
```

in my `web.config` which obviously using my local machine.

I've looked online and on here and can't seem to find a clear cut tutorial. Here is the database details:

**DATABASE SERVER**

```
mysql4.gear.host
```

with my username and password with reading and writing permissions.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it - I'm also using Entity Framework if that makes any difference?

EDIT:

This is my new connection string:

```
<add name="UniversityContext" connectionString="Server=mysql4.gear.host;Database=databasename;User Id=username; Password=password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

However, when I publish the website I get a runtime error?

Runtime error:

Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Console error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: what is your model for accesing db (codefirst or EF designer from db) 

and try it maybe it could help to you.

<add name="UniversityContext" connectionString="Data Source=mysql4.gear.host;Initial Catalog=databasename;User Id=username; Password=password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Answer (score 0):

IMO, best place for learning to write connection strings is here: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: Thanks, I've taken a look and updated my connection string but I'm getting a runtime error?

Comment: Run browser on your web server - you will see real, not masked with general error description, exception message.

Comment: I'm only using free hosting so not sure how I would even do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<add name="UniversityContext" connectionString="Data Source=mysql4.gear.host;Initial Catalog=databasename;User ID=username;Password=password" />
```

Comment: @James can you share runtime error details and config ?

Comment: @Ayvaras added to post.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create file with .udl extension and test configuration.

It could help you to find proper parameters.

Comment: maybe you should install ODBC for MySQL https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/